# Strange magnification behavior: scale starts at 1

Tags: swiftui, magnification

I want to pinch zoom an image on a view.

I have this code:

```
@State var progressingScale: CGFloat = 1

var body: some View {
  Image(imageName)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)

    .scaleEffect(progressingScale)

    .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
      .onChanged { value in
          progressingScale = value.magnitude
      }
      .onEnded {value in
        progressingScale = value.magnitude
      }

    )
}
```

This code works relatively well but suppose I scale the image up and lift the fingers. Now the image is huge.

Then, I try to pinch and scale it up more. The image goes back to `scale = 1` and starts scaling up again. I want it to start at the scale it was when the fingers were released the first time.

Cannot figure why... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the magnification to *stick*, you need to keep track of two values: the image's permanent scale (`imageScale`) and the current magnification value (`magnifyBy`).  The scale applied to the image is the product of these two values (`imageScale * magnifyBy`).

While the `MagnificationGesture` is in progress, just change the `magnifyBy` property.  When the gesture ends, permanently apply the magnification to the `imageScale` and set `magnifyBy` back to `1`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var imageScale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var magnifyBy: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
        
            .scaleEffect(imageScale * magnifyBy)
        
            .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    magnifyBy = value.magnitude
                }
                .onEnded {value in
                    imageScale *= value.magnitude
                    magnifyBy = 1
                }
                     
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW BRILLIANT! I was strugling to understand that, thanks to Apple's phony documentation. THANKS!!!!!!

Comment: OH, but this code has a problem. It will always scale from the center, not from where the user is pinching... I will open another question.